# Magento - SOAP API response incomplete when using a MAMP stack under Lion

Tags: magento, soap, soapui

I tested Magento's SOAP API using soapUI. I successfully logged in and got a login hash. 
Then I tried to retrieve a list of products and this worked fine.

This was on a Linux server using the latest version of Apache, mySQL and PHP.

I then created a backup of Magento and the database. I wanted to create a test environment on a Lion server using a MAMP stack. The Magento backup seems to work fine, but the SOAP API doesn't.

Again I used soapUI to get a login hash and tried to retrieve all products. But now the response seems to be incomplete:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="urn:Magento">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<ns1:catalogProductListResponseParam>
<result>
<complexObjectArray>
<product_id>7167</product_id>
<sku>000140</sku>
... etc ...
<complexObjectArray>34</complexObjectArray>
</category_ids>
<website_ids>
<complexObjectArray>1</complexObjectArray>
</website_ids>
</complexObjectArray>
<complexObjectArray>
<product
```

Why is the reponse incomplete under Lion/MAMP?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had a problem with incomplete SOAP XML responses once.

The **setup** was like this:

- Linux server
- Magento CE 1.5.1.0
- Usage of SOAP v2 with WS-I compliance enabled
- Call of sales_order.info

Even if you use a different Magento version and a different SOAP call, you may suffer from a similar bug as I did. The problem was that the **HTTP Content-Length header was calculated incorrectly for responses > 8000 bytes**.

**How to verify if you are affected by this bug**:

1. Execute a call which delivers a short response (e.g. "catalog_category.info" with just a single store-view and only few attributes). If the XML is complete, check if the response has a length <= 8000 bytes.
2. Copy the file app/code/core/Mage/Api/Model/Server/Wsi/Adapter/Soap.php to your app/code/local folder and edit the run() method. If you use the "wsdl" parameter in your SOAP URL, edit the first part of the "if" structure, otherwise edit the "else" part.

As the second way is the more accurate way to do it, I'll go with this.

1. Open the file and search for the ->setBody() method call. As you can see, there is some search/replace magic going on.
2. Write the result of the search/replace operations into a variable and log it for further examination. The code may look like this:

   ```
   public function run()
   {
       $apiConfigCharset = Mage::getStoreConfig("api/config/charset");

       if ($this->getController()->getRequest()->getParam('wsdl') !== null) {
           /* don't modify the first part ... */
       } else {
           try {
               $this->_instantiateServer();

               $content = preg_replace(
                       '/(\>\<)/i',
                       ">\n<",
                       str_replace(
                               '<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>',
                               "<soap:operation soapAction=\"\" />\n",
                               str_replace(
                                       '<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>',
                                       "<soap:body use=\"literal\" />\n",
                                       preg_replace(
                                           '/<\?xml version="([^\"]+)"([^\>]+)>/i',
                                           '<?xml version="$1" encoding="'.$apiConfigCharset.'"?>',
                                           $this->_soap->handle()
                                       )
                               )
                       )
               );
               Mage::log($content, null, 'soap.log');
               $this->getController()->getResponse()
                    ->clearHeaders()
                    ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)
                    ->setBody($content);
           } catch( Zend_Soap_Server_Exception $e ) {
               $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
           } catch( Exception $e ) {
               $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Execute the SOAP API call and open var/log/soap.log in your Magento directory. If the XML is complete in the log file but not in your response, then the Content-Length header is the problem.

**How to correct the Content-Length header**

1. Stay in your copy of Mage_Api_Model_Server_Wsi_Adapter_Soap and add one line to the code we just modified:

   ```
   public function run()
   {
       $apiConfigCharset = Mage::getStoreConfig("api/config/charset");

       if ($this->getController()->getRequest()->getParam('wsdl') !== null) {
           /* don't modify the first part ... */
       } else {
           try {
               $this->_instantiateServer();

               $content = preg_replace(
                       '/(\>\<)/i',
                       ">\n<",
                       str_replace(
                               '<soap:operation soapAction=""></soap:operation>',
                               "<soap:operation soapAction=\"\" />\n",
                               str_replace(
                                       '<soap:body use="literal"></soap:body>',
                                       "<soap:body use=\"literal\" />\n",
                                       preg_replace(
                                           '/<\?xml version="([^\"]+)"([^\>]+)>/i',
                                           '<?xml version="$1" encoding="'.$apiConfigCharset.'"?>',
                                           $this->_soap->handle()
                                       )
                               )
                       )
               );
               Mage::log($content, null, 'soap.log');
               $this->getController()->getResponse()
                    ->clearHeaders()
                    ->setHeader('Content-Type','text/xml; charset='.$apiConfigCharset)
                    ->setHeader('Content-Length',strlen($content), true)
                    ->setBody($content);
           } catch( Zend_Soap_Server_Exception $e ) {
               $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
           } catch( Exception $e ) {
               $this->fault( $e->getCode(), $e->getMessage() );
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Note the line:

   ```
   ->setHeader('Content-Length',strlen($content), true)
   ```

   We calculate and set the Content-Length header. The third parameter, true, is important because it tells the framework to overwrite the existing Content-Length header.
2. If this works, remove the Mage::log() call and rewrite the code for use in your own extension.

If you ask **why** this problem occurs I can't tell you exactly because I didn't hunt the bug all the way down.

From what I saw, everything is fine as long as the XML response has a length <= 8000 bytes. If the response is longer than 8000 bytes and the XML consists of x lines, the response is truncated by x characters. It looks like it is a problem with the different carriage return codes and/or with encoding issues which lead to the wrong calculation of the response content length.

Comment: Great, this worked. Thanks a lot. I will watch for the bug on the magento page and if it has been reported so far.

Comment: Glad I could help. fritz found an entry in the Magento bug tracker. Cross reference: [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/bug-tracking/issue?issue=12604)

Comment: Thank you! I was getting this error when I turned on WS-I compliance with Soap V2. It was giving the error "looks like we got no XML document" when I was logging in, debugging the log it had extra white space after the XML.

Comment: I have 1.11.1.0 and have the same bug. Indeed if my webservice returns a shorter response, the problem does not occur. Unfortunately your fix with `setHead('Content-Length',strlen($content), true)` does not solve this. `strlen($content)` is 333656. Any further suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Comment: i have to add, that I use the wsdl=1 parameter in my URL.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your PHP configuration changed. You're likely running into a PHP.ini `memory_limit` or `max_execution_time` error. You should be able to compare your PHP settings by creating a simple file on each server in your Magento root (it's important that you put the file in your Magento root because the .htaccess file might be overriding PHP settings) and comparing values:

**info.php**

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

You can also check your Apache error logs for additional information.

Comment: Well i checked the php.ini on the server and compared it to the one of the MAMP-Server. Except the memory_limit parameter which i changed to 265M i couldn't find any differences. In addition i found some wsdl parameters in the php.ini on the linux server, which i also tried to copy to the MAMP-Server. In the end i run into to same problems as i mentioned earlier. I will try to incorporate the changes the next response on this issue was posted and call back if i get some new information on this problem. thanks anyway

Comment: no sorry nothing neither in the apache_error.log nor in the php_error.log. i couldn't even find any error in the logs of the magento installation.