# Magento Soap Error - Premature end of data in tag definitions line 2

Tags: api, magento, soap, wsdl

My client is using Unleashedsoftware.com to connect to a Magento Store. But it gives this error.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
            <faultcode>WSDL</faultcode>
            <faultstring>
                SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://www.domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/' : Premature end of data in tag definitions line 2
            </faultstring>
        </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

When browsing  http://www.domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/ Firebug gives me “500 Internal Service Error”.

When I browse http://www.domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/, I am getting valid XML data.

I checked the server log files and it seems like:

```
[Thu Aug 30 22:22:25 2012] [warn] [client 92.92.92.92] mod_fcgid: stderr:  in /home/doaminuser/public_html/lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php on line 762
```

I been searching for couple of days now and today I tried to duplicate the entire site to another test server, and it seems to be working!  So that seems to be a server issue.

Please, anybody got any idea what could be the issue?

Is there any better way of debugging this issue, any sample code or debugging tips.

Magento version is 1.6.2

Thank you.

Comment: Have you been able to solve the issue ?

Comment: As @AlanStorm pointed out, "It's probably a server configuration issue of some kind".  So I had to move on to a dedicated server. The 'curl' command indicated that, the request was not completed.  So I assumed the server wasn't capable of processing such a request. I know this was not a solution. Please post any updates if you find anything.

Answer (score 3):

There's lots of times where Magento's SOAP API fails due to problems your Magento server has communicating with itself.

That is, PHP's SOAP implementation requires that the SOAP server itself fetch the WSDL file via `http`, and a local network configuration issue gets in the way of Magento fetching it's own WSDL.

You can debug this by SSHing into your Magento server, and running the following command

```
curl -l 'http://www.example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/' > /tmp/wsdl.xml
```

and then examining the `wsdl.xml` file.  Because you're performing this from your web-server, you may get different results than when you're performing it from your local browser.

Comment: I have memories of this. What worked for me was to put the hostname in /etc/hosts on the server plus the www alias on 127.0.0.1 However, in this instance the server was in the building rather than in some ISP place and the LAN had Windows computers on it. Windows users had downloaded lots of trojan-virus-porn things that were spending the whole time spamming the network so the real problem was with the Windows computers on the network, not with the server or with Magento. After fdisking the PC's the problem was solved.

Comment: Thanks Alan.  The site is hosted on a shared server, shell access not enabled.  Just waiting for the host to enable it for me.  I will update you once I tried these steps.  Never think of that!

Comment: @ewebs If you know PHP's curl functions you could do the same this by uploading a PHP file with the equivalent curl command there.

Comment: @AlanStorm I have no joy executing the suggested command. I tried using shell_exec, which is disabled.
I tied something simiilar http://bit.ly/PSH9mp. Seems like the xml is not fully retrieved. Please view the source. Here is the code I used:
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.domain.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);   
    print('<pre>' . print_r($output ,true) .'</pre>' );

Comment: @ewebs There's your problem.  Magento's reacting differently when the request comes from your own server.  It's probably a server configuration issue of some kind.  Get on your ISP/host for why.

Comment: @AlanStorm That was my initial thought as well, but now it is more clear. Thank you. Here is my phpinfo() - bit.ly/PSH9mp, in case this gives any idea. Could it be anything to do with execution/load times or anything like that? Another thing I forget to mention is, I run two stores/domains from this Magento installation.  Would it make any difference? Still waiting for the host to get back to me on some initial questions.

Comment: @AlanStorm I will wait for 'them' and let you know the feed back.  Thank you.

Comment: @AlanStorm Noticed this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620511/magento-soap-api-response-incomplete-when-using-a-mamp-stack-under-lion.  Tried but still no joy!  My client is on a differnt time zone, so it is not very easy to get things sorted as well.

Comment: @AlanStorm managed to execute the curl command directly through SSH. Similar incomplete results as before.  Got this message `curl: (18) transfer closed with 163341 bytes remaining to read`. Thanks Alan

Comment: @ewebs You need to be bringing this up with your system administrator/host. That's not me. Good luck.

Comment: This answer helped me realise that my website was in maintenance mode. Because I had my IP whitelisted, I didn't even realise this and it was the main cause of the API failure. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when calling the URL
`http://www.store.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/?wsdl`

After some time I received the message `500 - Internal Server Error` and a `Premature end of script headers` message in the apache error log.
After a whole day of research I figured out, that the `Timeout`-Directive of the Apache module (configured in httpd.conf on a Linux environment) was set to "20" which caused the server to send the 500 error after 20 seconds. The problem is, that in my case the Magento system needs a longer time to "crawl" through all wsdl.xml files in order to build the WSDL-output (if you are using Magento SOAPv2).
Maybe you should check your Timeout Directive..hope that helps.

Comment: I was trying to do this, but mine is a shared host.  Only limited permission!  So I am waiting for them to update the httpd.conf.  Is there any way we could update it for our local environment, any ideas?  Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 0):

> "I have memories of this. What worked for me was to put the hostname
>   in /etc/hosts on the server plus the www alias on 127.0.0.1 However,
>   in this instance the server was in the building rather than in some
>   ISP place and the LAN had Windows computers on it. Windows users had
>   downloaded lots of trojan-virus-porn things that were spending the
>   whole time spamming the network so the real problem was with the
>   Windows computers on the network, not with the server or with Magento.
>   After fdisking the PC's the problem was solved."

Thank You I've been struggling for 2 days with this on magento 1.6 and Windows Server 2008 adding this line to the hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`) solved the issue for me:

```
127.0.0.1   www.Domain.com
```

also remember to fix your magento soap (role) because the Roles Resources doesn't save in 1.6 unless you fix this file:

> MagentoRoot\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Api\Tab\Rolesedit.php

replace this:

```
if (array_key_exists(strtolower($item->getResource_id()), $resources) && $item->getPermission() == 'allow') {
```

with this:

```
if (array_key_exists(strtolower($item->getResource_id()), $resources) && $item->getApiPermission() == 'allow') {
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was the Mod_Security rule "PHP Easter Egg Access" was enabled.
Rule ID: 380800

Once disabled, the api access worked.

An indicator was in the Apache log file:

```
Jun 19 09:15:52 httpd[1024961]: [error] [client xyz.xyz.xyz.xyz] ModSecurity: [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec/99_asl_jitp.conf"] [line "116"] [id "380800"] [rev "1"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules - Virtual Just In Time Patch: PHP Easter Egg Access"] [data "phpe9568f35-d428-11d2-a769-00aa001acf42"] [severity "CRITICAL"] Access denied with code 403 (phase 2). Pattern match "php(?:e9568f3[56]-d428-11d2-a769-00aa001acf42|b8b5f2a0-3c92-11d3-a3a9-4c7b08c10000)" at REQUEST_URI. [hostname "www.yoursever.com"]...
```

Magento version: 1.7.0.2
PHP version: 5.3.26

More information about the PHP Easter Egg Access rule:
http://www.atomicorp.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5057
http://www.0php.com/php_easter_egg.php

For those wanting a quick test script to replicate the issue (useful when trying to convince your hosting provider that it's a problem on their end), use:

```
<?php
   $server = new SoapServer("http://<url to your magento shop>/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/");
?>
```

This is the line in /lib/Zend/Soap/Server.php that triggers the error.

In my case if you browsed to:
http://< url to your magento shop >/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/wsdl/1/
the xml was fine, but if you ran the above php script on the server, the error was given.

Answer (score 0):

This error most often appeared for me while omitting www for domain given in Magento SOAP url. Url has to match base url specified in the Magento config.